# Facebook wall photos are unavailable

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I am attempting to write a script to pull the wall photos from a Facebook Fan Page wall, and display them as a gallery on a different site.

I am looking at the jSON that is generated by the Facebook API, and the Album ID is: http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=278746938805288&id=239319006081415&aid=76076

Whenever I attempted to visit that URL however, it tells me "This content is currently unavailable:  The page you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may have expired, or you may not have permission to view this page."

I checked my Facebook settings, and I don't have any age or country restrictions set, and I made sure that the "only admins can see this page" box is unchecked.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to read data about your other album: 260606647285984

I received

```
{  
    "id": "260606647285984",   
    "from": {    
    "name": "Bikini Joe's",     
    "category": "Restaurant/cafe",     
    "id": "239319006081415"  },   
    "name": "Wall Photos",   
    "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=260606647285984&id=239319006081415&aid=72791",   
    "cover_photo": "260606650619317",   
    "count": 14,   
    "type": "album",   
    "created_time": "2011-08-08T23:57:05+0000",   
    "updated_time": "2011-09-22T17:02:49+0000"
}
```

And the "link" is working.

Can you check if album ID:278746938805288 is visible to 'public'? (OK)

And if all other options are the same as for your other albums?

[If you load details about album 278746938805288](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer#!/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=278746938805288) then notable difference to the result above is that the result does not contain neither "count" nor "cover_photo". So the problem might be that the album is empty?

Comment: The album in question is actually the wall photos, which is why this is so puzzling.  All permissions should be public for that - so I am puzzled as to why nothing would show up in the album data.  Thoughts?

Comment: Did you check this? If you load details about album 278746938805288 then notable difference to the result above is that the result does not contain neither "count" nor "cover_photo". So the problem might be that the album is empty?
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer#!/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=278746938805288